# How to convert KDE plasmoid's `metadata.desktop` to `metadata.json` using `desktoptojson`?

Tags: kde-plasma, plasmoid

I'm writing my first KDE plasmoid using QML. The [hello world example](https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Plasma5/QML2/HelloWorld) uses a `metadata.desktop` file, while [this KDE Plasmoid tutorial](https://develop.kde.org/docs/extend/plasma/widget/setup/) talks about a `metadata.json` instead and says that the [`metadata.desktop` is 'discouraged' now](https://develop.kde.org/docs/extend/plasma/widget/setup/#examples-of-mainqml) and a desktop file should be converted to json using `desktoptojson`.

However, when I browse the globally installed plasmoids under `/usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/` they all have both the `metadata.desktop` and `metadata.json`.

**First question: So, what is really recommended? Just the `metadata.json`? Or both?**

And, I wasn't able to find the `desktoptojson` tool. I'm using [Linux Mint and the `./kdesrc-build --initial-setup`](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=456205) for debian based systems says that it's "This is woefully incomplete and not very useful" ... I read that ["most users of this [i.e. `desktoptojson`] utility will use the CMake macro `kservice_desktop_to_json` as part of the process of building a plugin."](https://man.archlinux.org/man/desktoptojson.8.en). However, I haven't found the documentation yet how to use this.

**Second question: In case one should maintain both files (for whatever reason), should I use `desktoptojson` to keep them in sync? And if yes, how?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> First question: So, what is really recommended? Just the metadata.json? Or both?

In the current source code, most stock KDE applets such as the [task manager](https://github.com/KDE/plasma-desktop/tree/master/applets/taskmanager/package) use metadata.json's and have dropped the metadata.desktop's. It may be that the desktop files you have locally are left over from old versions, the new format was installed but the old one was never deleted.

> Second question: In case one should maintain both files (for whatever reason), should I use desktoptojson to keep them in sync? And if yes, how?

The man page on Arch you linked to has all the information. The tool is part of the package `kservice`. Find the equivalent in the repository for your distribution. Then, to use it

1. as part of a CMake macro:

```
add_library(myplugin MODULE ${myplugin_SRCS})
kservice_desktop_to_json(myplugin myplugin.desktop)
```

2. directly on the command-line:

```
desktoptojson -i myplugin.desktop -o myplugin.json
```

Comment: Hm, I'm on Linux Mint and there is no package `kservice` ... any idea?

Comment: No, sorry. You'll have to find out how to find the package that provides a command on your distro. Worst case you could just write the json file manually.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to **convert metadata.desktop to metadata.json** - inside the  directory where the metadata.desktop file is:

```
$ desktoptojson -s plasma-applet.desktop -i metadata.desktop
```

Remove metadata.desktop file:

```
$ rm metadata.desktop
```

And just in case - to install plasmoid:

```
$ kpackagetool5 -i Plasmoid-name
```

To remove plasmoid:

```
$ kpackagetool5 -r Plasmoid-name
```

(Usually just copy-paste to /home/user/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids does the same trick as install - remove).